# How can I have titles with normal font size with AUCTeX+Emacs?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm wondering how to modify the way AUCTeX show titles.

By defaut, the titles are too big for me and they take too much place in my screen.

[image]

(ignore the red underlining created by flyspell set with a dictionary which is not English).

I would like to have the same font size for everything in my document. I believe the color is sufficient to emphasize titles.

I tried to set `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` to 'color' according to [AUCTeX manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html)

> User Option: font-latex-fontify-sectioning
>
> Per default sectioning commands will be shown in a larger,
>   proportional font, which corresponds to a number for this variable.
>   The font size varies with the sectioning level, e.g. ‘\part’
>   (font-latex-sectioning-0-face) has a larger font than ‘\paragraph’
>   (font-latex-sectioning-5-face). Typically, values from 1.05 to 1.3 for
>   font-latex-fontify-sectioning give best results, depending on your
>   font setup. If you rather like to use the base font and a different
>   color, set the variable to the symbol ‘color’. In this case the face
>   font-lock-type-face will be used to fontify the argument of the
>   sectioning commands.

However, I obtained an error for the setting `'color'`:

> custom-variable-set: This field should contain a number (floating point or integer)

I tried then to set this setting to 1. (the default is 1.1) with the idea that 1. should be the normal font size.

I obtained this error (I cannot see my titles anymore):
[image]

Comment: According to the help it should be *from 1.05 to 1.3*.

Comment: `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1.0)` should do the trick, because `1.` is treated as an integer and `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1)` seems not to work.

Comment: @giordano 1.0 works (I tried 1). Any idea why 'color' couldn't do the trick?

Comment: @Sigur 1.05 to 1.3 are the values which give the "best" results according to the doc. It's possible to set higher or lower values.

Comment: @ppr `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 'color) (font-lock-fontify-buffer)` works for me.

Comment: @giordano with your code, my titles are not in yellow anymore (but in green). Is it the case for you too?

Comment: @giordano Another question: why `'color` and not `'color'`?

Comment: For me, at least, this was an important question.  I've been curious about AUCTEX, but all the screenshots I've seen show it with a variety of font sizes--like some attempt to convert a text editor into a (bad) wysiwyg editor.  I don't know how many are like me, but AUCTEX evangelists might take this to heart and make it clear that the font-sizes-all-over-the-place look is not required.  Am playing with AUCTEX now.  Not sure yet if I want to stick with it, but certainly don't hate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the `color` value of the `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` variable add the following code to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 'color)
```

You must use `'color` and not `'color'` because the `'` character is used to [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) the next Lisp symbol and Emacs would interpret `'color'` as the `color'` symbol, but AUCTeX doesn't accept that value for the `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` variable.

Instead, if you want to set `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` to 1 use

```lisp
(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1.0)
```

Setting `font-latex-fontify-sectioning` to `1.` doesn't work because in Emacs Lisp `1.` is an integer (see [Integer Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Type.html) on the GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual) and `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1)` doesn't work either due to a bug ([now fixed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=da395f4c139c750a58565bf8e5e6b622a37aec3b)) inside the current (11.87) stable version of AUCTeX.

Comment: Thank again for this answer. Any idea to do the same for Beamer documents (reduce titles size to normal)?

Comment: Customize `font-latex-slide-title-face` (`M-x customize-face RET font-latex-slide-title-face RET`) and set height to `1.0`.

Comment: @giordano it seems `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1)` does not work with 12.1.1+ (current dev version). (and 1.0 does not work either but ``'color`` works -- Emacs 24.5 here)

Comment: @jfbu it does work for me. Please, try to replicate the issue and report to the bug tracker

Comment: I have it a hook and I am using `(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook #'jfbu/TeX-mode-hook t)`. With `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1.0)` or any other numeric value `1.5`, `2.0` I tried out, the effect seems nil. With `(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 'color)` it appears to work (but uses same coloring as in comments, I do have some custom theme). I do not control everything on that system but I think I tried it on my mac and had same result. Here I do additionally `(unload-feature 'tex-site)` and AUCTeX is installed via ELPA in my home `.emacs.d`.